# How do I get rid of newlines between words?

Tags: c, io

I'm learning C and system programming. I'm trying to read a text file and print out the words in lower case.  All non-alpha characters will be delimiters.  I am getting the output below. Can someone take a look at my code and give me some hints on how to remove the lines between words?  Thank you!

**Here is the beginning of my text file:**

The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Iliad of Homer, by Homer

This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org

Title: The Iliad of Homer

Author: Homer

Translator: Andrew Lang, M.A., Walter Leaf, Litt.D., And Ernest Myers, M.A.

Posting Date: January 14, 2012 [EBook #3059]
Release Date: February, 2002

Language: English

**Here is my output:**
the
project
gutenberg
ebook
of
the
iliad
of
homer

by
homer

this
ebook
is
for
the
use
of
anyone
anywhere
at
no
cost
and
with
almost
no
restrictions
whatsoever

you
may
copy
it

give
it
away
or
re
use
it
under
the
terms
of
the
project
gutenberg
license
included
with
this
ebook
or
online
at
www
gutenberg
org

title

the
iliad
of
homer

author

homer

translator

andrew
lang

m
a

walter
leaf

litt
d

and
ernest
myers

m
a

posting
date

january

ebook

release
date

february

language

english

..........

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 256

int end_line(FILE *file, int c)
{
    int endLine = (c == '\r' || c == '\n');

    if (c == '\r')
    {
        c = getc(file);
        if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ungetc(c, file);
    }

    return endLine;
}

int get_word(FILE *file, char *word, size_t wordSize)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int c;

    //skip non-alpha characters
    while ((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF && !isalpha(c) && isspace(c)){
        ;   //do nothing
    }

    if (c != EOF)
        word[i++] = c;

    //read up to the next non-alpha character and store it to word
    while ((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF && i < (wordSize - 1) && isalpha(c) && !end_line(file, c))
    {
        c=tolower(c);
        word[i++] = c;
    }
    word[i] = 0;
    return c != EOF;

}

//Main Function
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *input = argv[1];
    FILE *input_file;
    char word[SIZE];

    input_file = fopen(input, "r");

    if (input_file == 0)
    {
        //fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure
        perror("Canot open input file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (get_word(input_file, word, sizeof(word)))
        {
            //do something with word;
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
    }

    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `else` part you are printing with `\n`... Apply some mathematics and you it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `printf("%s\n", word);`, the **`\n`** is an escape sequence that represents a newline character. So that's where the newline characters are coming from!

As for the extra newlines when punctuation is followed by a space, take a closer look here:

```
//skip non-alpha characters
while ((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF && !isalpha(c) && isspace(c)){
```

The comment doesn't match the code, which is suspicious. It's also suspicious that so much is going on inside the while() test. There's no point in writing such terse code, and it just makes debugging harder. For whatever reason, some C programmers like writing unreadable code... but don't imitate them. :)